# How to Calculate the Values for a Column having Formulas , The Formula Variables being columns from the Same SQL Server Table

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, common-table-expression, calculated-columns

I have the table contents as shown in this picture:

[image: screenshot]

The formula column contains the the column names as variables in the formula expression.

I am trying to get a computed column Score corresponding for each `emp_id`,`Tsk_id` and `processed date` which would be calculated dynamically based on the formulae given in the formula column and push it to a temp table

I have tried to achieve it by dynamic SQL within a cursor using the below code which has been successful. Can Anyone suggest a better way to do it, maybe using a CTE or something ?

```
DECLARE @EMP_ID nVARCHAR(255)
DECLARE @TSK_ID nVARCHAR(255) 
DECLARE @PROCESSEDDATE nVARCHAR(255) 
DECLARE @SQLCMD nVARCHAR(max) 
DECLARE @SQLTEXT nvarchar(max)

DECLARE db_cursor CURSOR FOR  

SELECT EMP_ID,TSK_ID,PROCESSEDDATE from dbo.[Formula_Cal] group by EMP_ID,TSK_ID,PROCESSEDDATE


OPEN db_cursor   
FETCH NEXT FROM db_cursor INTO @EMP_ID,@TSK_ID,@PROCESSEDDATE

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0   

BEGIN   

      Set @SQLTEXT = (Select formula from dbo.[Formula_Cal] where EMP_ID=@EMP_ID and TSK_ID =@TSK_ID and PROCESSEDDATE=@PROCESSEDDATE )
      Set @SQLCMD ='select emp_id,TSK_ID,convert(decimal(18,2),( ' +@SQLTEXT+ ')) As Score  FROM [Formula_Cal] where TSK_ID = '+@TSK_ID+' and EMP_ID = '+@EMP_ID 
      --Select @SQLTEXT
      --Select @SQLCMD
      insert into dbo.TMP_ACHSCR(emp_id,TSK_id,Score)
      Exec sp_executesql @SQLCMD

      FETCH NEXT FROM db_cursor INTO @EMP_ID,@TSK_ID,@PROCESSEDDATE  
END   



CLOSE db_cursor   
DEALLOCATE db_cursor
```

Comment: codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: I don't really see the need for a cursor here. You could just select it all in one dynamic SQL query, no?

Answer (score 0):

No this is easiest way (with minimal rewriting). You can access this with rewriting our formulas into function.

Comment: Thanks Deadsheep , but there is no defined set of formulas used here , it may vary for every row. So writing formulas into a function i believe would limit only to a fixed set of formulas which would ask of hardcoding , aim is to do the calculation dynamically.